# How to add additional network segment?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking

Long-standing network (A) is as follows

Network A: 192.168.37.0/24
GatewayA: 192.168.37.1/255.255.255.0 (eth1)
ADSL on ppp0 (via eth0)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
xxx.xxx.128.191 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
192.168.37.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 ppp0
```

where GatewayA is a Linux (CentOS) server with 2 NIC's.

Clients on addresses 192.168.37.14/255.255.255.0 & 192.168.37.13/255.255.255.0 can ping GatewayA, each other and the internet. So, all behaves as expected thus far.

netstat -nr for 192.168.37.14

```
Routing tables
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.37.1       UGSc           35      117     en4
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              5  1178472     lo0
169.254            link#10            UCS             0        0     en4
192.168.37         link#10            UCS             6        0     en4
192.168.37.1/32    link#10            UCS             1        0     en4
192.168.37.1       c8:3a:35:d5:76:9f  UHLWIir        37    13927     en4   1200
192.168.37.8       0:23:6c:7b:6c:9b   UHLWI           0        0     en4   1024
192.168.37.9       link#10            UHRLWI          0      174     en4
192.168.37.11      0:26:4a:16:6:da    UHLWIi          1   422531     en4   1135
192.168.37.13      link#10            UHLWIi          1     1401     en4
192.168.37.14/32   link#10            UCS             0        0     en4
192.168.37.69      e0:6:e6:6d:f9:f7   UHLWI           0      123     en4    447
192.168.37.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        6     en4
```

Client at 192.168.37.13 is another CentOS server equipped with a second NIC and running `ifup eth1` with ifcfg-eth1 as follows

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.37.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
```

results in

Network B: 10.37.0.0/16
 GatewayB: 192.168.37.13/255.255.255.0 (eth0)
           10.37.0.1/255.255.0.0 (eth1)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.37.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.37.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.37.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Adding route to Network B from GatewayA

```
root@GatewayA # route add -net 10.37.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth1
```

Client on 10.37.0.10/255.255.0.0 (GW=10.37.0.1) can ping local GatewayB. But this same client is not able to ping anything on 192.168.37.0/24 or the internet.

Routing table is

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.37.0.1       10.37.0.10    266
        10.37.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link        10.37.0.10    266
       10.37.0.10  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.37.0.10    266
    10.37.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.37.0.10    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.37.0.10    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.37.0.10    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.37.0.1  Default 
===========================================================================
```

with ping and traceroute as follows

```
Pinging 10.37.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.37.0.1: bytes=32 time=156ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.37.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 156ms, Maximum = 156ms, Average = 156ms

Pinging 192.168.37.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.37.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),

    Tracing route to enrico [192.168.37.1] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.37.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  Tracing route to 192.168.37.14 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     6 ms     6 ms     4 ms  10.37.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Client on 192.168.37.14 (GW=192.168.37.1) is able to ping 10.37.0.1 but is not able to ping 10.37.0.10.

```
PING 192.168.37.1 (192.168.37.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.37.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.254 ms

PING 10.37.0.1 (10.37.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.37.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.314 ms

PING 10.37.0.10 (10.37.0.10): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from enrico (192.168.37.1): Destination Host Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 2236   0 0000  3f  01 698e 192.168.37.14  10.37.0.10 

traceroute to 10.37.0.10 (10.37.0.10), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  enrico (192.168.37.1)  0.355 ms  0.240 ms  0.272 ms
 2  enrico (192.168.37.1)  3001.015 ms !H  3000.862 ms !H  3000.809 ms !H
```

Changing the route on GatewayA changes the message from traceroute but not the outcome

```
root@GatewayA # route del -net 10.37.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth1
root@GatewayA # route add -net 10.37.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.37.13
```

as follows

```
traceroute to 10.37.0.10 (10.37.0.10), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  enrico (192.168.37.1)  0.408 ms  0.239 ms  0.239 ms
 2  gateway (192.168.37.13)  0.352 ms  0.298 ms  0.245 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
```

Both gateways have net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and iptables=off.

From what I have read it seems to me that this should work - but I can't see what is missing.

Comment: I would confirm if ipv4 forwarding is enabled with: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward    That should output a 1 if it is.

Comment: Try adding the route 10.37.0.0/16 on GatewayA with a gateway IP address not just the interface. `route add -net 10.37.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.37.13` If that doesn't work, please post traceroutes from both directions. Also to access the internet from the 10.37.0.0/16 network you will need the appropriate NAT on GatewayA

Comment: I think Cha0s is correct here, if you haven't specified the GW, as far as linux knows, it should just use the default gateway.

Comment: l0sts0ck - confirmed ipv4 forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Can post a traceroute from the opposite direction? 10.37.0.10 to 192.168.37.14. Also can you post the `route -n` output of all machines involved?

Comment: Cha0s - Added ping and traceroute output before and after making your suggested change to routing table from 192.168.37.14. Still collecting output from the other end (10.37.0.10).

Comment: @joe4warners Yes, but the traceroute you posted is from 192.168.37.14 to 10.37.0.10 only. Not the opposite direction. Also you haven't posted the routing tables of all machines involved in the trace. Without a full view of your routing tables we cannot figure out what may be the problem.

Comment: I believe that completes all of the requested info. Sorry it took me a while to collate it all.

Comment: How about a trace from 10.37.0.10 to 192.168.37.14? Also from the routing tables I see that those are windows clients. By default windows will drop traffic from outside their local subnet. According to your traceroute from 192.167.37.14 the packets go thought gatewayA and then gatewayB (as they should) and then you get timeouts which is consistent with windows' default firewall.

Comment: My bad @Cha0s, requested traceroute is there now. One client (192.168.37.14) is OSX, the other (10.37.0.10) is Windows. I turned the Windows Firewall off but couldn't see any difference - my bad again for not spotting that.